# Why can't I open Visual Studio Code on Linux?

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, centos7

I have worked on it for a whole week, but I can't still solve the problem.

Each time I install Visual Studio by `yum install code-**x86_64.rpm`.

After that, I write the command `code` on my terminal, but nothing happens!

I have remade CentOS7 five times and reinstalled Visual Studio Code more than 10 times.

Comment: From the VSCode website "The code bin command does not bring the window to the foreground on Ubuntu#

Running code . on Ubuntu when VS Code is already open in the current directory will not bring VS Code into the foreground. This is a feature of the OS which can be disabled using ccsm."  I know you said centos, but I'd check to see if its running minimized somewhere anyway

Comment: Did you use the official Microsoft repo: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-visual-studio-code-on-centos-7/

Comment: Do `type -p code` to confirm it is installed in a location that is in your `PATH`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this command `sudo yum install code`.

For more details, you can visit [Visual Studio Code docs for Linux](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux)

And if you want to open the project you can use `code .` command in terminal, but make sure your terminal should be in project directory.

Comment: Sry,can u explain what does "terminal should be in project directory" means?

Comment: It means your terminal working directory should be your project directory.

Comment: For Linux:
Such as If your project folder is in '~/Project' then the terminal working directory should be '~/Project' and then try the command ' code .'
For Windows:
'c:\myProject> code .'

Comment: thanks for your help!!!!!!Wish you a good day!!!!!!!!!